# use polar notation to write $(-2+2i)^3$ in polar form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification

I am supposed to go from eulers equation to polar. I am looking for solution verification:

$$r = \sqrt{-2^2+2^2} = \sqrt{8}$$

$$\theta = \arctan \Big(\frac{2}{-2} \Big) = \arctan(-1)= -45$$

since Graphing $-2+2i$ falls in the second quadrant I took $180 - (-45) = 225$

so we have $$\Big(\sqrt{8}e^{i225}\Big)^3 = \sqrt{8}^3[\cos((225)(3))+i\sin((225)(3))]$$

Comment: You're correct. You can always check this by explicitly calculating the expression that you get.

Comment: it should be 135 not 225

Comment: Note that $\tan 225° \ne -1$

Comment: how did you get 135?

Comment: im supposed to be using arctan? right?

Comment: $135^\circ$ is in the second quandrant. $225^\circ$ is in the third quadrant.

Comment: oh okay so I got -45 and subtracted that from 180 giving me 225, am I supposed to ignore the negative sign?

Comment: I guess my problem is what do I do when the angle is negative?

Comment: -45 degrees is in the 4th quadrant. To get something in the 2nd quadrant, just add 180 degrees. $$\tan(x+180^\circ) = \tan(x)$$

Comment: so if I got -300 degrees and wanted to get something in the second quadrant say 100 I would do what?

Comment: don't worry about it. you're good. you did -45x3 = -135 degrees, which is the same as 225

Comment: -300 is in the first quadrant (the same as 60 degrees). Here, there will not be any angle in the second quadrant that will yield the same value from the $\tan$ function.

Comment: The angle needs to be in radians, not degrees. For instance, $e^{i360}\neq 1$

Comment: You should write $(-2)^2$ since $-2^2 = -1 \cdot 2^2 = -1 \cdot 4 = -4$ while $(-2)^2 = 4$.

Answer (score 1):

In polar we have $8^{3/2}e^{-\frac{3πi}4}$.  This I did in radians.  $π/4=45°$.

Comment: can you do it in degrees to verify whether or not I did it properly my professor does not care if its not in radians

Comment: $3\cdot45=135$.